# Is it still "dangerous to rely on binary frameworks that use Swift"?

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

In the Swift blog https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2 from July 11th, 2014, it states:

> "if your project uses frameworks to share code with an embedded
>   extension, you will want to build the frameworks, app, and extensions
>   together. It would be dangerous to rely upon binary frameworks that
>   use Swift — especially from third parties. As Swift changes, those
>   frameworks will be incompatible with the rest of your app. When the
>   binary interface stabilizes in a year or two, the Swift runtime will
>   become part of the host OS and this limitation will no longer exist."

It's now been almost 3.5 years since then, which is more than "a year or two".  Xcode 9, iOS 11, and Swift 4 are current standard at this time.  Is this still true?  And if so, when is this expected to change?

I want to convert an SDK from Objective-C to Swift, and it would need to be distributed as a binary (at least in part).

...

**Update:**  I found this https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160725/025676.html which states under "Possible Swift 4 Phase 2 Efforts":

> "- .swiftmodule stability: At some point we need to stabilize the
>   “.swiftmodule” binary file format (or replace it with a different
>   mechanism) to allow 3rd party binary frameworks.  This is a very large
>   amount of work over and above what is required for ABI stability of
>   the standard library."

Does this answer my own question?  Is that where we are right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per an [answer provided by Apple](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/268430#268430):

> > Is it still "dangerous to rely on binary frameworks that use Swift"?
>
> Yes.
>
> This stuff is complex so [I’m](https://forums.developer.apple.com/people/eskimo) going to defer to the [Swift ABI Stability Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABIStabilityManifesto.md) for the details.  However, the executive summary is that:
>
> - ABI stability is planned for Swift 5 (see [this page](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution))
> - Module format stability still doesn’t have a target date
> - Distributing binary frameworks without both is a bad idea